# Wget copy text from html

Tags: html, linux, unix

I'm really new to programming and linux/unix so I was wondering what command I can use to copy the text only of a webpage and save it in a file in the directory. I want to copy the text of something like this

http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi12/cse130-a/pa5/words

would wget do it? also what specific commands get it saved into the directory?

Comment: What do you mean by "just the text?"

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `wget` like you wondered about would be:

```
wget -O file.txt "http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi12/cse130-a/pa5/words"
```

The `-O` option lets you specify which file name you want to save it to.

Comment: That, plus a `-q` to spare the download spam :)

Comment: @favoretti I guess I like knowing if the connection was made :)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be:

```
  curl -s http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi12/cse130-a/pa5/words > file
```